# SQL - return only where specific rows match

Tags: sql

I have a large table (millions of entries), structured like this:

```
PASS_NUMBER
PASS_LOCATION
```

A specific pass (PASS_NUMBER) may have any number of rows. For example:

```
PASS_NUMBER     PASS_LOCATION
     1                A
     1                B
     1                D
     2                A
     2                B
     2                E
     3                A
     3                D
     3                E
```

I need an SQL query that returns the PASS_NUMBER for every pass that is valid in ALL the locations in a specific set of PASS_LOCATIONS. For example:

```
PASS_LOCATIONS {A,B} should produce PASS_NUMBERS {1,2}
PASS_LOCATIONS {A,D} should produce PASS_NUMBERS {1,3}
PASS_LOCATIONS {E} should produce PASS_NUMBERS {2,3}
```

The set of PASS_LOCATIONS may be quite large (say up to 50 items) and the table is likely to get VERY big (possibly into the billions of rows), so efficiency is important.

Any thoughts?

Comment: 1. Thousands of entries with 2 columns is not a large table, it's tiny. Millions would be moderate.
2. What sql engine are you using?
3. What have you tried so far?
4. Does simple `SELECT DISTINCT PASS_NUMBER WHERE PASS_LOCATION IN ()` not cover this question, or am I missing something here?
5. Assuming you already have a clustered index on PASS_NUMBER, you may consider adding index on PASS_LOCATION with included column PASS_NUMBER (or an equivalent construct in rdbms other than mssql) to improve read performance.

Comment: 1 - I'm compiling the table at the moment. The row count is 66159170 and I'm about 7% of the way through. So it's probably billions of rows rather than millions. 2) Microsoft SQL server. 3) Haven't found anything that works, but I'm fairly new to SQL. 4) That returns ANY in the list - I need ALL from the list. 5) Yes - I will index it carefully, along those lines probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a semi join (`WHERE EXISTS`):

```
    SELECT
      p1.PASS_NUMBER 
    FROM
      PASS p1
    WHERE
      p1.PASS_LOCATION = 'A'
      AND EXISTS
      (SELECT 
          * 
       FROM 
         PASS p2
        WHERE 
          p1.PASS_NUMBER=p2.PASS_NUMBER 
          AND p2.PASS_LOCATION='B')
    ;
```

You can find a complete example on [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f7e2/2).

Comment: Ah - that should work, yes. Except we'll have fifty or so nested "AND EXISTS" commands. Is this likely to impact performance much?

Comment: In fact, once properly indexed that seems to be very fast indeed. On the partial table (now about 80 million rows) it's pretty instant. Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PASS_NUMBER
FROM PASS_TABLE
WHERE PASS_LOCATION IN (PASS_LOCATIONS)
```

Where PASS_LOCATIONS is a comma-separated list of locations.

If you want to make sure performance is ok, consider indexing the Pass_Location column (perhaps followed by pass_number in the same index so the optimizer can do a single index lookup) - but this depends on a lot of things including the specific database you're using as well as the actual data itself. Millions of rows really isn't necessarily a 'lot of data' for modern RDBMS's, but of course it depends on your specific implementation and requirements.

Comment: Hmmm - what I really need is a function that returns any PASS_NUMBER that is valid in ALL of the locations in the set, rather than any of the locations.